# how to do a simple opacity change of an element on scroll with only pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have elements with opacity set to 0 change to 1 when brought into the user's view. how do I do this using only pure javascript? NO JQUERY, please.  Thank you in advance for any help offered.

I have tried adding a class and removing a class when in view and nothing is working. This is a very simple task and I am just not sure what to do here. I have sought out documentation but all that I have found either include jquery or are more complicated than what I am looking to do.

```
<div class="outer">

        <div class="booger" ></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>

        <div class="booger"></div>
</div>


body {
box-sizing: border-box;

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;

text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}

.outer {
width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: grey;

}

.booger {
display: inline-block;
width: 49%;

margin: 50px 30px;
padding: 100px 0;
background-color: darkgray;
opacity: 0;
}

.boogers {
opacity: 1;
} 

var toBeShown = document.querySelectorAll(".booger");

function showIt() {

const scrolled = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) -                        
(toBeShown.height/2);

const imageBottom = scrolled.offsetTop + scrolled.height;
const isHalfShown = scrolled > scrolled.offsetTop;
const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;

if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
scrolled.classList.add('boogers');
} else {
scrolled.classList.remove('boogers');
}
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', showIt);
```

Comment: Jquery is JavaScript underneath. Go from there

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for more elaboration. this is something I have been able to do with jquery, now I want to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731416/todd-chaffee) on all the reasons he cited, but I think the logic can be cleaned up quite a bit.

All you want to watch for is when the top of the item scrolls into the center of the viewport, add an class, when it is below, remove said class.

I put together a codepen to demonstrate.

https://codepen.io/bickle66/pen/YbamYq

```
function showIt() {
  const toBeShown = document.querySelectorAll(".booger"); // consider adding :not(.scrolled) to selector to reduce the number of iterations if you don't want to support scrolling up

  // consider taking this outside of the loop and resetting it on window resize to optimize the loop
  const halfScreen = window.innerHeight / 2;

  toBeShown.forEach((item, i) => {
    const scrolled = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight);// - (item.offsetHeight/2);

    if (item.offsetTop - window.scrollY < halfScreen) {
      item.classList.add('scrolled');
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('scrolled');
    }
  })

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', showIt);
```

Although I love your class naming standard, ;-) I changed the `boogers` class to `scrolled` to be a bit more obvious on it's meaning

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked EXACTLY how I wanted it too. I still need to go through the math and utilize console.log so I can appreciate both the words of wisdom provided by you and Todd.

Comment: Awesome. glad I could help. If it's all good can you accept it as the answer? thx

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. The code below sort of does what you want, but the math to determine when a div is shown is not 100% correct. I'll leave it up to you to fix that.

The main problem is that `document.querySelectorAll` returns *an array of elements*. So you need to process that array of elements, checking each one to see if it is in view, and then adding / removing classes for just that element.

Also, there is no `height` attribute for elements. Use `console.log` liberally to explore what properties are available and which one suits your purpose.

```js
var toBeShown = document.querySelectorAll(".booger");

function showIt() {

  toBeShown.forEach(function(elem) {

    const scrolled = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) -                        
    (elem.offsetTop/2);
    
    const imageBottom = elem.offsetTop + scrolled;
    const isHalfShown = scrolled > elem.offsetTop;
    const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
 
    if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
      elem.classList.add('boogers');
    } else {
      elem.classList.remove('boogers');
    }

  });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', showIt);
```

```css
body {
box-sizing: border-box;

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;

text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}

.outer {
width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: grey;

}

.booger {
display: inline-block;
width: 49%;

margin: 50px 30px;
padding: 100px 0;
background-color: darkgray;
opacity: 0.3;
}

.boogers {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="booger" >hay</div>
  <div class="booger">b</div>
  <div class="booger">c</div>
  <div class="booger">d</div>
  <div class="booger">e</div>
  <div class="booger">f</div>
  <div class="booger">gee</div>
  <div class="booger">haytch</div>
  <div class="booger">hi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will start there for sure! I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: so I have tinkered with the math and I can't seem to get this to work in fact it seems the math is firing the near opposite of what I am looking to do, where do you suggest I begin? as far as I can tell I have each element set to "appear" when half way into the viewport, but that is definitely not what is happening. also, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: You need to debug it step by step. Use lots of `console.log` to look at the value of each variable in your calculation to see if they make sense or if you need to use something different.

Comment: Oh, see Bryan Jones' answer. That works from what I can see.